# trigger compare records and insert values from other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Please advise for trigger procedure for the following action:

there are 2 tables `table_1` and `table_2` which have similar columns: `col_a, col_b, col_c.`

When in PHP statement inserts in the `table_1 (col_a)` some string value it has to be compared with `table_2 (col_a)` and in case if they are identical, values from `table_2 (col_b, col_c)` have to be inserted into `table_2 (col_b, col_c)`

Please advise

Comment: Integrate the question with what you have produced so far

Comment: UPDATE table_2
SET ( (col_b, col_c) =
SELECT FROM table_1 (col_b, col_c)
IF table_1 (col_a) = table_2 (col_a)

Comment: Does this mean there is only one row per table? Or last index of table_1.col_a compared to last index of table2.col_a?

Comment: I have removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually usr.

Comment: of course not only one... FOR EACH ROW

Comment: @BorisGrebnevskyi You need to compare values from two tables, so you could use the SQL LEFT JOIN keyword to check for this.

Comment: is "col_a" of both tables is unique?

Comment: @lat long ... table_1 is the list of streets (col_a) with unique id_street (col_b) and not unique postcode (col_c)
JS copied data from table_1 (col_a) in dropdown menu in the webform 

$('#street').autocomplete({source: 's54646.php});

so when I choose some street name from this list and submit it's inserted into table_2 (col_a) and other data from this form:
$qstreet ="";
if (isset ( $_GET ['submit'] )) {
$elem = $_GET;  
foreach ( $elem as $key => $value ).......

Comment: @lat long ... ... in this moment has to start trigger which will choose values from table_1 (col_b, col_c) and update table_2 ( col_b, col_c), so we can avoid insert values for these two columns from web form and simplify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger function would be something like this. You can customize it according to your own columns data types and names.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_trgr() RETURNS trigger AS
  $BODY$
    DECLARE
      val_c TEXT;
      val_b TEXT;
    BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT col_b INTO val_b FROM table_1 WHERE col_a=NEW.col_a;
    SELECT DISTINCT col_c INTO val_c FROM table_1 WHERE col_a=NEW.col_a;

    NEW.col_b := val_b ;
    NEW.col_c := val_c ;

    RETURN NEW;
    END;
  $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: DECLARE
      val_b TEXT;
       BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT street_54646.id_street INTO val_b FROM street_54646 WHERE street=NEW.street; 

    NEW.id_street := val_b ;
    
    RETURN NEW;
    END;

generate 
 Warning: pg_insert(): Query failed: ERROR: relation "street_54646" does not exist LINE 1: ...T 
    DISTINCT street_54646.id_street FROM street_546... ^ 
    QUERY: SELECT DISTINCT street_54646.id_street 
    FROM street_54646 WHERE street=NEW.street

Comment: Error says it does not found the table street_54646

Comment: it was need to clarify exact way, included schema: ... FROM iota_cmac.street_54646 ... SOLVED

Comment: Thats good. yes schema name was needed if you are not using the default public schema